# Applying 7-segment display using counter VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am beginner and it's my first VHDL code
It's a code to apply 7_segment display using counter
When compiling the 2 codes the main code had no errors while the test bench code gave 6 errors 
any help ?

Main code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

ENTITY counter IS
port (clk,rst: IN std_logic;
    count: OUT std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) );
END counter;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF counter IS
signalcount_sig: integer range 0 to 7;
BEGIN
    PROCESS(clk,rst) 
    begin
        if(rst='1')then
            count_sig<=0;
        elsif(rising_edge (clk))then
            count_sig<= count_sig+1;
        end if;

        if (count_sig=0)      then count <= "1000000";
        elsif (count_sig=1) then count <= "1111001";
        elsif (count_sig=2) then count <= "0100100";
        elsif (count_sig=3) then count <= "0110000";
        elsif (count_sig=4) then count <= "0011001";
        elsif (count_sig=5) then count <= "0010010";
        elsif (count_sig=6) then count <= "0000010";
        elsif (count_sig=7) then count <= "1111000";
        end if;
    end PROCESS;
END rtl;
```

Test bench code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

ENTITY test_counter IS
END test_counter;

ARCHITECTURE beh OF test_counter IS

    COMPONENT counter IS
    port (clk, rst: in std_logic;
count: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
    END counter;

    SIGNAL clk, rst: std_logic;
    SIGNAL count: std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

    BEGIN 
        V1: counter PORT MAP 
        (clk<=clk ,
        rst<=rst ,
        count<=count);

        clock : PROCESS
        begin
        wait for 5 ns; clk<= not clk;
        end PROCESS clock;

        reset : PROCESS
        begin
        rst<= '1';
        wait for 10 ns; rst<= '0';
        wait for 80 ns;
        end PROCESS reset;

    END beh;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the test bench code, the component declaration end is not to be `END counter;` but:

```
END component counter;
```

or just:

```
END component;
```

For the component instantiation, then mapping from port name (formal) to signal (actual) does not use `<=` but `=>`, so the code instantiation should be:

```
V1: counter PORT MAP
  (clk   => clk,
   rst   => rst,
   count => count);
```